# Can I call Twitter Bootstrap scaffolding spans inside my CSS as a mixin instead of a class?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I understand I can add a `class="span3"` to a `div`, but what if I want to give the equivalent  attributes to another class via LESS?

Example:

```
<div class="span3">This width is span3</div>
<div class="anotherClass">I want to make this also span3, but without explicitly calling it out</div>
```

In LESS I want to do something like:

```
.anotherClass {
    .span3();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What about "extend"? Have you even googled for this functionality?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  You mention LESS, but your tags include Sass.  Which preprocessor are you actually using?

Comment: @cimmanon, LESS, but I tagged SASS in the event that the answers are similar.

Comment: @kleinfreund, Yes, but I still don't have an answer.  If it's just a matter of a google search, can you share the correct search terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins) says you can include any class or id ruleset by referencing it without brackets:

```
.anotherClass {
    .span3;
}
```

For your particular case, however, you can't `include` the compiled Bootstrap CSS and be able to mix in the class like that, and the Bootstrap LESS source doesn't outright define classes/mixins called `.span1`, `.span2` etc.

In [mixins.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L573) there's a mixin called `.span(@columns)` that's used to calculate the width, depending on `@gridColumnWidth` and `@gridGutterWidth` along with the argument. You could call it using:

```
.anotherClass {
    #grid > .core > .span(3);
}
```

which would only give your target the width that would be calculated for a `.span3`.

If that's what you're going for then that's fine, however there are also other rules that would apply to an element named `.span3`, e.g. `[class*="span"]`. So if you're trying to mirror those as well you won't be able to do it programmatically, you'd have to comb through the files manually and copy the attributes you want.

Comment: This results in a `NameError: .span3 is undefined in /path/file.less:1000:3`.  Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: The class you're mixing in has to be accessible from the current file to be able to use it. Find the file where `.span3` is defined and `include` it.

Comment: Thanks @freejosh, I'm digging in now.  I do include mixins.less at the beginning of my file.less, like so: `@import "mixins.less";` and I include other variables from my variables.less just fine (colors, for example: `@blue`).

Comment: Your `#grid > .core > .span(3)` didn't error out on me, so that's progress, but it doesn't hold all the same styles as the explicit `class="span3"` and ends up stacking instead of aligning horizontally.  But I think I'm on the right track now at least.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
.anotherClass {
    .span(3);
}
```

Will do the job. Since bootstrap is defining a generic class spanX for creating spans.

Comment: This results in a `NameError: .span is undefined`

Comment: @Ryan I am guessing you are importing bootstrap after your your anotherClass

Comment: I'm not sure how / why the hierarchy works, but in my case I needed the full `#grid > .core > .span(3);`