# Unable to compile bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compilation

I am trying to compile bootstrap 2 (I am obliged to use this version because it is included in the framework that I use), and I have a problem when compiling the less files:

```
Command failed: NameError: #grid > .core > .span is undefined in bootstrap/less/navbar.less on line 199, column 3:
198 .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
199   #grid > .core > .span(@gridColumns);
200 }
```

However, if I comment this line, the compilation works, but my website's layout is a mess afterwardss. I have already tried the solution described at

[Less v2 does not compile Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628309/less-v2-does-not-compile-twitters-bootstrap-2-x)

But, the layout is still broken. Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628309/less-v2-does-not-compile-twitters-bootstrap-2-x