# Bootstrap 2.3.2 & Less.js error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am getting the following error when compiling bootstrap.less using less.js. Using Less is brand new to me, so this is all pretty new to me so I am not sure what I am missing here.

my

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/static/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
```

results in this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) b.exports {
    type: "Name", 
    filename: "http://domain.com/static/bootstrap/less/navbar.less", 
    index: 4564, 
    line: 199, 
    callLine: NaN…
}
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:13
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:13
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:14
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:14
    h.parse.w @ less.min.js:14
    f._onSequencerEmpty @ less.min.js:16
    c.tryRun @ less.min.js:16
    f.run @ less.min.js:16
    h.parse @ less.min.js:14
    b.exports.i @ less.min.js:14
    b.exports.e @ less.min.js:14
    j @ less.min.js:13
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:13
    b.exports.g.loadFile.doXHR.e.type @ less.min.js:13
    h @ less.min.js:13
    b.exports.g.doXHR @ less.min.js:13
    b.exports.g.loadFile @ less.min.js:13
    j @ less.min.js:13
    k @ less.min.js:13
    b.exports.n.refresh @ less.min.js:13
    b.exports.n.refresh @ less.min.js:13
    2../add-default-options @ less.min.js:13
    e @ less.min.js:13
    a @ less.min.js:13
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:13
    i @ less.min.js:13
    (anonymous function) @ less.min.js:13
```

Comment: Set ["development" option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-setting-options) to get human-readable errors. As for the error, Bootstrap 2 is too old and not compatible with current Less versions (see  [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628309) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553367) for known incompatibilities and possible workarounds, or use same aged Less 1.3.3 to compile instead).

Comment: found my answer here after turning on development mode...

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628309/less-v2-does-not-compile-twitters-bootstrap-2-x